# NSObject category class method not recognized

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash

I created a category on top on NSObject, because I want ALL of my classes to inherit 2 class methods I wrote:

```
@interface NSObject (MyCategory)

+ (MyEnum) getXYZ;
+ (void) setXYZ:(MyEnum)myEnum;

@end
```

Then I imported this category into my PCH file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "NSObject+MyCategory.h"
#endif
```

Then I used the method in one of my classes:

```
[[self class]getXYZ];
```

and got this error in runtime:

```
+[MyClass getXYZ]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xd04f4
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '+[MyClass getXYZ]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xd04f4'
```

Did I do something wrong?
Is the category written well?
Are class methods not inherited?
Should I use [super class] instead of [self class]?
Is the PCH file the place to import my category?

Thanks,
Nur

Comment: You have an @implementation file, right?

Comment: @Stephen Darlington, I do have an implementation file and the methods are declared there

Comment: @nume the rate at which you mark answers to your questions as accepted, using the green checkmark. Yours is only 25%.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you have not defined getXYZ  method in the implementation file (.m) of category(NSOBject).and for calling the class method of NSObject...use

```
[NSObject getXYZ];
```

not

```
 [[self class]getXYZ];
```

Comment: Actually `[[self class] someClassMethod]` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your category is in an other project that your main project you have to add linker flag "-all_load"

Comment: This is not true anymore since Xcode 4.2: the linker bug on the categories was fixed in LLVM 3.0, so `-all_load` is not needed anymore since these versions. Only `-ObjC` is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't import your Categories in your prefix header (.pch) file. In most cases you only need your category in a few other files, so only import them there. Only import files in your prefix header that are used throughout the whole project.

If you're sure you want to have that category in your prefix header, try setting the Build Setting `Precompile Prefix Header` to `No`. Or clean the project. Sometimes Xcode forgets to recompile the prefix header.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks! I need the category on top of ALL my other classes. I'm adding a new functionality to all of them, as inheritors of NSObject. thanks